# Uploading to S3 via POST?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

I've been trying to upload to S3 via post, and found a good example:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>S3 POST Form</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body> 
    <form action="https://s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
      <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private"> 
      <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost/">
      <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="YOUR_POLICY_DOCUMENT_BASE64_ENCODED">
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="YOUR_CALCULATED_SIGNATURE">
      <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
      <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

      File to upload to S3: 
      <input name="file" type="file"> 
      <br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I know what the "Access Key" value means, but what about the policy document and calculated signature? How do I find or create those?

Comment: This is late, but policy basically defines what is your bucket expiration, what is its permission, who can access it, it is a json object which one has to encode in base64 to send across with this form, here is the link to it..
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

here is the link, describing how to create the signature for aws4
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$form['policy'] = '{ "expiration": "2090-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "idclkimages"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://idclkimages.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "PUT-YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE/20901229/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20901229T000000Z" }
  ]
}';

$form['policy_encoded'] = base64_encode($form['policy']);
$form['signature'] = base64_encode(hash_hmac( 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256', base64_encode(utf8_encode($form['policy'])), 'PUT-YOUR-SECRET-KEY-HERE',true));


?>


<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="http://idclkimages.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://idclkimages.s3.amazonaws.com/index.php" />
    Content-Type: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption" value="AES256" /> 
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="PUT-YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-HERE/20901229/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20901229T000000Z" />

    Tags for File: 
    <input type="input"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<?php echo $form['policy_encoded'] ?>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<?php echo $form['signature'] ?>" />
    File: 
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>

</html>
```